# How do I use block IDs in WorldEdit for Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I type:

//set 7271

To change it to a modded block, it says 7271 isn't a valid block name.

Is there any way I can make it understand block IDs?

Comment: What block do you think 7271 is?

Comment: http://railcraft.wikispaces.com/Speed+Rail+%28Rail%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because, well, 7271 isn't a valid block name. In fact, it doesn't refer to anything at all in vanilla Minecraft. Additionally, even if it does refer to a mod-related ID, that would be an item ID, not a block ID, and WorldEdit doesn't always play too nice with mods.

If you need a list of block IDs, you can check the wiki [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values#Block_IDs_.28Minecraft_Official_Release.29).

Comment: All items have values above 255, making it easy to separate the Block IDs from the Item IDs. -MinecraftWiki

Comment: It's a modded block. http://railcraft.wikispaces.com/Speed+Rail+%28Rail%29 to be precise.

Comment: Not sure if WorldEdit supports Block IDs above minecraft's default 255.

Comment: There is, unfortunately, no way to use Railcraft rails in WorldEdit. Even using `//stack`, it will convert it to vanilla rails. Sorry. I tried it before, attempting to replace a long line of rail with speed rails. Unfortunately, RailCraft rails don't play nice with WorldEdit.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is because you're using the item ID of the block, not the block ID. WorldEdit works fine when using the block IDs, but not the item IDs (as there's no way to determine what block it's attached to).

There are a few ways to get around this, however, such as using WorldEdit's `/info` tool to grab the block ID, or copying the block and using `#clipboard` instead of the ID.

Source: WorldEdit Developer. More info @ https://madelinemiller.dev/blog/worldedit-mod-blocks/

Answer (score -1):

Use the full name of the block:

```
//set track:hs_track
```

Comment: what if the block has additional data, like brownstone from TinkersConstruct? JEI  says that the id is #6341/7, which means that the id itself is not sufficient.